# JMeter: design isssues

Tags: jmeter

Please help me for the follow two questions:

1. Is it possible to set Jmeter up so that when we start GUI of the program and there is 'View Results Tree' the Option: Scroll automatically? to be checked by default?
   [image]
2. And second one: Is it possible to create shortcut keys for Zoom In, Zoom Out:
   [image]

Or, if this is not possible, at least set different Values for them in some properties JMeter file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's [unchecked and it's hardcoded](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.5/src/components/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/visualizers/ViewResultsFullVisualizer.java#L440) and cannot be changed (at least in [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5))

   if you want to amend the behaviour change `autoScrollCB.setSelected(false);` to `autoScrollCB.setSelected(true);` and [re-build JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/building.html)
2. Since JMeter 5.3 you can use `Ctrl + Alt + mouse wheel` to change fonts size.